# How do I know which widget has the focus with urwid?

Tags: navigation, urwid

I am designing a Python interface with `urwid` and I have several elements that cannot be reached using the cursor navigation keys (i.e. <kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>right</kbd>) and that's indeed what I want. What I'd like is to implement a circular navigation using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

There are three components I'd like to reach using this technique — namely a list box that is comprised of radio buttons, an edit box and a button to the right of the edit box. My application is built around a class that derives urwid.WidgetWrap. It contains a frame, the body of which is the listbox, the footer contains the edit box.

So far I've figured out I could trap the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key from the main loop's `unhandled_input` callback... but I have no idea whether it's the way to go or not. Besides I haven't figured out yet how to detect which one of these three widgets has the focus.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to give it a good read in [the urwid documentation for the Container widgets](http://urwid.org/manual/widgets.html#container-widgets).

Each Container widget is supposed to keep track of which which widgets has the focus in a given moment, and they have the `get_focus_path()` and `get_focus_widgets` methods for finding the widgets in focus.

It looks the default container widgets use this [`WidgetContainerMixin`](https://github.com/urwid/urwid/blob/master/urwid/container.py#L39-L107) class which you can inspect to find more.

As for the right way to implement the focus handling, I believe the best way would be to create custom widgets (either inheriting the existing ones or creating wrappers with `urwid.WidgetWrap`) which would share the focus handling behavior, but using `unhandled_input` is probably a good starting point to explore these at least.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I just needed to read the docs. I now understand what I had to implement and why.